# How to write nice looking paragraph in string. Xml file in android studio project?

Tags: xml, string, textview, styles

I am working on a simple android application and I want to show a story in text view, so I am writing the whole text in string.xml file.  But I am not able add few extra space just before first word in new paragraph.

As an example, I want to write like this (I want to start second line after few space at starting)

```
He is not bad bad crazy.
         Once he saw that picture.
```

I have tried the tags to add blank space as we use in html text but it did not worked.

Please help me, i will be very helpful.

Comment: Can you add the XML of your story to the question, so we can see what you’re trying?  Also, what are you displaying your story in?  A web browser?  A GUI control (if so, what toolkit)?

Comment: Sorry for bad quality of the question sir, i will add the code soon (commenting through phone)

Answer (score 1):

Hm... i use control character like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character

if you want to double tab then do like...

```
He is not bad bad crazy.\n\tOnce he saw that picture.
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir/madam(sorry,  i never heard you name and can't find it online, i am really sorry)

Comment: '\n' does not work . please try yourself first before posting solution !